# Wait for async function to end

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following function that works fine, except I need to wait until it finishes to execute the next statement:

```
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth = function () {
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        zohoAuth.state = utils.uuid();

        const url = zohoAuth.authorizationURL();

        zohoAuth.popUp(url);
        getAuthCodeFromCatalyst();
        //setTimeout(getAuthCodeFromCatalyst,1000);
        function getAuthCodeFromCatalyst() {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                (async function waitForFoo() {
                    const gotAuthState = await zohoAuth.getUserDataFromStorageState(zohoAuth.state)
                    await gotAuthState;
                    if (gotAuthState) return resolve();
                    setTimeout(waitForFoo, 1000);
                })();
            });
        }


        console.log("bottom of zoho auth")
        return true;
    // });
}
```

I call the function with this:

```
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth();
console.log("done waiting");
```

How do i wait for this to finish?

Comment: Await it? Use .then? Also why do you have a regular function that returns a new Promise that wraps an async IIFE, rather than just writing an async function?

Comment: Also, awaiting `getUserDataFromStorageState` and then awaiting the result looks odd. Are you sure you're using this tool correctly?

Comment: The above function works for what I want it do do. I am waiting for the user to press OK, then reading the result from a database. So I am calling 'getUserDataFromStorageState' every second. Which the function does. I just need to wait until I get the answer from the database

Answer (score 2):

You're making this harder on yourself. Make sure to avoid the [explicit promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) -

```js
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth = function () {
  zohoAuth.state = utils.uuid();
  const url = zohoAuth.authorizationURL();
  zohoAuth.popUp(url);
  return zohoAuth.getUserDataFromStorageState(zohoAuth.state);
}
```

You can access the result by attaching a `.then` handler to the result of your function call -

```js
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth()
  .then(authState => console.log("bottom of auth state", authState))
  .catch(console.error)
```

If you want to use `async` and `await`, go ahead. If an error occurs, don't catch it. Instead allow it to bubble up and be handled by the caller -

```js
async function doAuth (...) {
  const authState = await zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth()
  console.log("received auth state", authState)
  return "done" // or whatever
})

doAuth().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider `awaiting` on the promise. Below snippet shows the difference of using `await` -

```js
const asyncFunction = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inside promise');
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function callWithoutAwait() {
  asyncFunction();
  console.log('after without await function');
}

callWithoutAwait();

async function callWithAwait() {
  await asyncFunction();
  console.log('after with await function');
}

callWithAwait();
```

Comment: @Jamiec, it shows how to await promises.

Comment: @Jamiec, I have edited the snippet so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed below is the code. Thanks for the help!

```
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth = function() {
    zohoAuth.state = utils.uuid();
    const url = zohoAuth.authorizationURL();
    zohoAuth.popUp(url);
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (async function waitForFoo() {
            const gotAuthState = await zohoAuth.getUserDataFromStorageState(zohoAuth.state)
            await gotAuthState;
            if (gotAuthState) return resolve();
            setTimeout(waitForFoo, 1000);
        })();
    });
}
```

And this is the call:

```
zohoAuth.zoho_oAuth()
  .then(authState => console.log("bottom of auth state", authState))
  .catch(console.error)
```